# Red Hat Kickstart: How do I Prevent partitioning?

Tags: centos, xen, redhat, lvm

I'm currently working on a new virtualisation setup using Xen, and Centos for my workplace.  We intend to deploy the domUs into LVM volumes.  Currently, the only thing preventing this from working as smoothly as we'd like is the Kickstart script's insistence on partitioning.  This is the relevant part from our current KS template (which I've been messing with):

```
# Partitioning
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=xvda
part / --size=0 --grow --ondisk=xvda --fstype=ext3
```

This sets up a single partition and installs to it - which would be fine, but I'd prefer if there were *no* partitions, and installed directly to the existing LVM (so that we could then mount the LVM from the dom0 for backup and maintenance purposes).

It's possible I'm doing something wrong, and should be exporting the volume as xvda1 rather than xvda - which I'm more than happy to amend - but I'm still not sure how I'd navigate the Kickstart!

I'd really appreciate any help :).  Cheers in advance!

Comment: I think I've figured it out, will reply with the answer tomorrow if it tests OK.

Export the LVM as xvda1 rather than xvda, get rid of the clearpart command, and use --onpart=xvda1 rather than --ondisk=xvda.

Comment: Did you try use existing option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having Anaconda use a whole disk as a device for a filesystem isn't possible currently with Anaconda according to the Anaconda mailing list. It will be made possible in Fedora 13.

The workaround that was suggested was to do it in the %post section of the kickstart file, eg. umount /mnt/mountpoint, mkfs.ext3 /dev/whatever

Comment: Hi Tim, yeah, that's what I found all those months ago.  I should have updated this!  But you're entirely correct; in the end I gave up and just let it do its thing :).

Answer (score 1):

You should have one partition on the disk that you add into LVM. It can be the whole disk. Here's the disk-related bits from the kickstart file I'm using for building VMware hosts:

```
ignoredisk --drives=sdb,sdc
clearpart  --drives=sda --all
part /boot  --fstype ext3 --size=256 --asprimary --ondisk=sda
part pv.01  --grow        --size=100 --asprimary --ondisk=sda
volgroup vg0 pv.01 --pesize=32768
logvol /        --fstype ext3 --name=rootlv --vgname=vg0 --size=5120
logvol swap     --fstype swap --name=swaplv --vgname=vg0 --size=512
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile there is a solution. The following line should prevent anaconda to create a partition and makes a PV on the disk.

```
part pv.01 --onpart=sdb
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rm /dev/xvda1
ln -s /dev/xvda /dev/xvda1
```